# Graph database two nodes have a relationship with another node ONLY if both are true

Tags: neo4j, nodes, relationship, graph-databases, janusgraph

like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRGuM.png

A and B are related to C but ONLY if both A and B are true.

I'm currently using Neo4J as my graph database, but I'm not sure it has this capability. I'd be open to switching to a different graph database if it meant that the free version had this capability.

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j (and any other graph database I guess) a relation exists or does not exist. As long as we're not using quantum computing, it's binary.
But, you can definitely retrieve paths, or create/project virtual graphs based on conditions, which could include the one you mention.